# Where do I find the definitions of vim's understanding of a language, such as Ruby?

Tags: vim, syntax

I'm interested to write custom syntax definitions, and I'd a base to start from.  Where does Vim house the syntax definitions?

I presume there is a file with some regex statements that are associated with symbols I see defined in syntax-coloration files, e.g. `vimCommentString`, `vimCommand`, `vimCmdSep`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for files named `ruby.vim` in your `$VIMRUNTIME` folder. In my case that results in the following files:

```
/usr/share/vim/vim73/compiler/ruby.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/ruby.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/indent/ruby.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/ruby.vim
```

The last one is most likely what you are looking for.

Comment: that's the madness I was looking for ~

Answer (score 3):

The Vim documentation is very good. Here is a selection to get you started.

- Probably the best place to start on actually getting the syntax highlighting to do what you want is the Vim User Manual chapter "Your own syntax highlighted", `:help usr_44.txt`.
- For some of how it determines filetypes and related things, see the `syntax-loading` help.
- For pretty much everything you need to know, read the `filetype` help file.
- For creating a new filetype, `new-filetype`.
- Concerning where files are loaded from, `'runtimepath'`.

Note that there is separation between syntax definitions and highlighting. You can, however, see where the *highlighting* is defined with the assistance of the `verbose` command. Where `:hi vimCommentString` will show you *what* `vimCommentString` is highlighted as, `:verbose hi vimCommentString` will show also show you *where* `vimCommentString` highlighting was defined. (`:verbose` is handy for things like `set` as well if you've got a misbehaving script setting an option you don't want.)

Comment: For `:let` `:verbose` is completely useless: vim does not record where variables are defined.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. But at least it does for `set`. Can't think why I would have been under that impression...

Comment: @ChrisMorgan the regex that define the syntax are not where you explained.  I was mistaken to think that symbols like `vimCommentString` would be involved in the **syntax definitions**.  Your answer is very interesting, though, and will probably help in other projects.  Thanks.

Comment: @NewAlexandria: it is; `vimCommentString` is a vimscript syntax item. For Ruby you'd be dealing with `rubyComment` and other such things. As for where they are defined, the `'runtimepath'` stuff is the key to that.

Answer (score 0):

Basing your own custom syntax definition on an existing (hopefully similar) one is a good idea; however, be aware that you may also inadvertently copy mistakes and old baggage with it. Vim syntax highlighting is powerful and therefore complex, but there is good documentation starting at `:help usr_44.txt`.